# Swift SceneKit - How to align a node's y-axis to coincide with some SCNVector3?

Tags: swift, 3d, geometry, transform, scenekit

Let's say I have a node whose y-axis is in the direction SCNVector3(A, B, C) and I want its y-axis to be oriented in the direction SCNVector3(D, E, F).

How would I go about doing it?

I believe what I need is a transform for the Euler angles of the node but I don't quite know how to obtain the transform formulas or a transform matrix. There might also be a simple pre-existing SCNKit function that I'm not aware of.

I would appreciate if you could take a look.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use this function on this node:

```
func look(at worldTarget: SCNVector3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems like the way to go, will notify once I've tried it.